# Poor IE6 Performance: Should I use DIV instead of HTML Tables (massive page!)?

Tags: html, performance, internet-explorer, html-table, profiling

I'm dealing with a massive page. It contains many html tables and usually with "width=100%", and obviously, without the definition of the columns's width. Because of that, I'm having performance problems with Internet Explorer 6. My client (a bank) uses Internet Explorer 6 with old computers, so I can't tell them (but I wish I could) to use Chrome or Firefox.

I've been reading about performance issues when IE deals with Html Table. My question is: 
should I define the width of the tables and columns, or switch to DIV's? I know it's possible to migrate to DIV's after some work, but I'm not sure if IE is faster to render DIV's than html tables.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> IE is faster to render DIV's than html tables

**it's true.** All browser renders table-free markup faster because browsers not need to wait while all the table content is loading.

*Also, div-based layout is more simple to support*